# How to initialize struct pointer via reflection

Tags: go, reflection

My goal is to take a `nil` pointer to a struct (but could be any type), passed as an `interface{}`, and initialize a struct in its place.

My test code ([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/VIqQyc5s8I)) is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Foo struct {
    Foo string
}

func main() {
    var x *Foo
    var y interface{} = x
    fmt.Printf("Before: %#v\n", y)
    fmt.Printf("Goal: %#v\n", interface{}(&Foo{}))

    rv := reflect.ValueOf(y)
    rv.Set(reflect.New(rv.Type().Elem()))

    fmt.Printf("After: %#v\n", y)
}
```

I hope the code is self-documenting.  But the goal is essentially to convert `y` which begins as an uninitialized pointer to `Foo`, (`(*main.Foo)(nil)`) into a pointer to an initialized (zero-value) instance of`Foo`: `&main.Foo{Foo:""}`.  But I'm getting `reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value`.  I don't understand why the value I'm attempting to set is unaddressable.  I've spent the day reading through the source code to the standard library JSON unmarshaler, and other SO posts, but am still clearly overlooking something.

If I peel away the outer `interface{}`:

```
rv := reflect.ValueOf(y).Elem() // Remove the outer interface{}
rv.Set(reflect.New(rv.Type().Elem()))
```

the error becomes `reflect: call of reflect.Value.Type on zero Value`.

Comment: Using a loop implies that there may be arbitrarily many layers, but there are only three: the interface type of the variable, the pointer to the value, and the value itself.

Comment: @Adrian: In production,there may be an arbitrary number of layers. But here, clearly there aren't. I've removed the loop.

Comment: How would you end up with an arbitrary number of layers?

Comment: @Adrian: `SomeUnmarshalWrapper(&result)` followed by `func SomeUnmarshalWrapper(i interface{}) { json.Unmarshal(&i) ...` or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var x *Foo
var y interface{} = x
fmt.Printf("Before: %#v\n", y)
fmt.Printf("Goal: %#v\n", interface{}(&Foo{}))

// Must take address of y to set it. Dereference with Elem() to get value for y
rv := reflect.ValueOf(&y).Elem()

// Interface element type is *main.Foo, dereference with Elem() to get main.Foo
t := rv.Elem().Type().Elem()
rv.Set(reflect.New(t))
fmt.Printf("After: %#v\n", y)
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/n39yPzJVpe)

You can also assign `y` instead of setting it via reflection:

```
var x *Foo
var y interface{} = x
fmt.Printf("Before: %#v\n", y)
fmt.Printf("Goal: %#v\n", interface{}(&Foo{}))
rv := reflect.ValueOf(y)
t := rv.Type().Elem()
y = reflect.New(t).Interface()
fmt.Printf("After: %#v\n", y)
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/qDlmg32z4c)

Comment: I second this answer. Learned something new :)

Comment: Would there be a way to set `x` through `y`? Because `x` is still `(*Foo)(nil)`.

Comment: Already found out. You need to pass a pointer to the pointer. I asked my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70968737/set-value-of-interface-representing-nil-pointer-using-reflect-in-go) and it was answered. In case anyone ever wonders.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `rv.CanAddr()` is `false` and consequently you cannot set it (`rv.CanSet()` is `false`).

Problem: if you have a pointer to nil it is not addressable. A pointer to a pointer to nil (or a pointer to an interface) however is addressable.

You can get your example to work in different ways:

- initialize x to be non-nil (probably not the point here)
- set y to a new Value with `reflect.New(..)`

  ```
  func main() {
      var x *Foo
      var y interface{} = x
      fmt.Printf("Before: %#v\n", y)
      fmt.Printf("Goal: %#v\n", interface{}(&Foo{}))

      rv := reflect.ValueOf(y)
      y = reflect.New(rv.Type().Elem()).Interface()

      fmt.Printf("After: %#v\n", y)
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your actual use case, it's hard to say what solution you require, however [this works](https://play.golang.org/p/Fere9XyDck) for your example:

```
var x *Foo
var y interface{} = x
rv := reflect.ValueOf(y)
y = reflect.New(rv.Type().Elem()).Interface()
```