# Set value of interface representing nil pointer using reflect in Go

Tags: go, pointers, reflection

My question is similar to [How to initialize struct pointer via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061568/how-to-initialize-struct-pointer-via-reflection).

I have an interface that represents a nil pointer. I want to update the value behind the nil pointer.

I took the code from one of the examples in the answers to the question mentioned above, but my situation is slightly different, and the given solution isn't working.

Inside `InitNilPointer()` the value actually does become `&Foo{}`. But the result at the call site remains `(*Foo)(nil)`. How can I use reflect to update `foo` in `main()` to `&Foo{}`?

The situation is the following

```golang
func main() {
    var foo *Foo

    InitNilPointer(foo)

    // Want: &main.Foo{A:""}
    fmt.Printf("Want: %+#v\n", &Foo{})

    // Got: (*main.Foo)(nil)
    fmt.Printf("Got: %+#v\n", foo)
}

// InitNilPointer initiates the given pointer to a nil value to become a pointer to 
// a value. E.g. (*Foo)(nil) becomes &Foo{}.
func InitNilPointer(source interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(source)
    if reflect.Indirect(v).IsValid() {
        return
    }
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(&source).Elem()
    t := rv.Elem().Type().Elem()

    // This only updates the value locally. The call site still has a nil pointer. SAD.
    rv.Set(reflect.New(t))

    // source: &main.Foo{A:""}
    fmt.Printf("source: %+#v\n", source)
}
```

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/3plCwRzWHeP

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you pass to a function, a copy is made. If you pass `foo`, no matter what the function does, it can only modify the copy but not the original `foo` variable.

So you **must** pass `&foo` (and modifying the *pointed* object will modify `foo`):

```
func main() {
    var foo *Foo

    InitNilPointer(&foo)

    fmt.Printf("Want: %+#v\n", &Foo{})
    fmt.Printf("Got: %+#v\n", foo)
}

func InitNilPointer(source interface{}) {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(source).Elem()
    if reflect.Indirect(rv).IsValid() {
        return
    }
    t := rv.Type().Elem()

    rv.Set(reflect.New(t))

    // source: &main.Foo{A:""}
    fmt.Printf("source: %+#v\n", source)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/GMBdJwHtqb6)):

```
source: (**main.Foo)(0xc00000e028)
Want: &main.Foo{A:""}
Got: &main.Foo{A:""}
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks for your solution! Just for my understanding, `var foo *Foo` is already a pointer, right? I was expecting reflect to be able to modify the value that that pointer points to. But if I understand what you're saying correctly, the function receives a copy of that pointer, which it cannot update?

Comment: @minitauros Yes, that's right. The function could modify the pointed object, but not the pointer stored in the `foo` variable–unless you pass the address of the `foo` variable itself.